# Regular expression for closing curly brace NOT preceded by a period

Tags: regex

How can I express "not preceded by" in a regular expression? I want to search for "}" but only when it is not directly preceded by ".". I am searching in notepad++, but I presume any regular expression engine will treat this the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\.)}
```

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/mX7hQ5/1)

The expression `(?<!\.)}` has a negative lookbehind to match the literal `}` character if it is not preceded by the `.` character.

Comment: based on what I see at the "Example here" link  - this matches } _followed_ by .  no?

Comment: In your example, I want it to match all three cases, but not  .}